# How do I determine a file's original location?

Tags: linux, mv

I used `mv` to move all files matching a specific pattern into a folder. How can I determine (after moving files) where a specific file came from?

Is there any chance of determining the location after I used the command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. You could potentially set up `auditd`  or something like that to trace what happened but that would have been set up before the command.

One possible solution is to look into the shell history to see where/how the file was moved and determine the original location from there. This is however largely unreliable.

Comment: And how can i look into the shell history to see that? It is reliable since i know what filename to look for! -- I used the comand find / -name "*.doc" -exec mv {} DOCS/ \;

Comment: @TudorutRobert with that you are out of luck. you could maybe try to do an analysis on the file system but this is rather complicated and may be impossible if it was across different file systems.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do an system analysis then? It was only in a Linux File System. I really need those files location, and im gonna try anything i can.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any chance of determining the location after i used the command?

Yes, with some luck (and probably a lot of manual work).

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a tool that can [undelete files](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_ext2).

Although the linked page shows how to recover deleted files, the procedure seems to work even when files are moved out of a directory and not only when deleted (aka removed?) from it. I tried recovering moved files with success, both in case of files that are moved to a directory within the same partition or to a directory in a different partition with a different filesystem (ext4 to NTFS).

The tool allows you to navigate your file system and shows deleted/moved files in red. So if you find a moved file, you know where this files was moved from. It may require a lot of manual work unless you can narrow your search to a few locations that you suspect, or if you find a way to automate testdisk to do this for you (given that the deleted files are all documents as you have mentioned in a comment).

An alternative workaround is to check the cache of any software tools you used to read/modify these documents when they were in their old locations. Some applications may keep links to these documents in order to implement a 'Recent Files' menu.

Comment: Interesting looking tool — and, by the way, you misspelled its name: it is TestDisk.  Did you, by any chance, have anything to do with developing it?  Anyway, the TestDisk documentation that you linked to says that it can "undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem — so it is, apparently, limited to those filesystem types.  (And we still don't know what filesystem the OP is using.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I will edit it right now. I've noticed that the documentation didn't mention ext4 but it worked for me when I tried it. And no, I am not related to the development of TestDisk :)

Comment: If it supports ext2, there's a good chance it'll support ext3 and ext4, since those two are supersets of ext2.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ulrich: this is generally, basically impossible.  But

- It may depend on exactly what version of Linux you are using,
  and what type of filesystem the files are on. 
  I'm not very familiar with these,
  but it looks like [journaling file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) like [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) and [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)
  might keep something analogous to an audit trail of changes. 
  It might be possible to reverse engineer one of these to see
  what you would need to do to rollback a filesystem change,
  which would show you where the files came from. 
  Or maybe not; I don't know whether this is possible.

  Note: if this is possible,
  it may require that you stop using the filesystem ASAP,
  so that new changes do not overwrite the journal of the moves
  that you want to backtrace.
- The "obvious" answer —
  if you have a sufficiently recent backup from before the move,
  you can look at it to see where the files were.

Comment: a backup is a good starting point. A listing of the files on the backup might be enough, although there might be double names at the source for the `mv`. Depending on that you might have to restore and compare hashes on the files.